# Output keeps repeating itself

Tags: python

I've created a function that prints the index and length of the 'True' elements. I've managed to produce the answer, but the output keeps on repeating itself.

```
data = [True, True, False, False, True, 
                       True, True, True, True, False,  
                       False, True, True]  

def find (stat, min):
    newlist = []
    start = 0
    end = 0
    x = [index for index, ele in enumerate(data) if ele]          
    for index,value in enumerate(x):
        if index < len(x)-1:
            if x[index+1]> value+1:
                end = index +1
                newlist.append(x[start:end])
                start = end
        else:
            newlist.append(x[start: len(x)])
    for i in newlist:
        x = []
        x = [i[0],len(i)]
        print(x)
    return x
    
    
for k in range(len(data)):
    final = find(data[k],2)
    print(final)
```

The output I wanted was, [[0,2],[4,5],[11,2]] but the output gives me:

```
[0, 2]
[4, 5]
[11, 2]
[11, 2]
[0, 2]
[4, 5]
[11, 2]
[11, 2]
[0, 2]
[4, 5]
[11, 2]
[11, 2]
[0, 2]
[4, 5]
[11, 2]
[11, 2]
[0, 2]
[4, 5]
[11, 2]
[11, 2]
[0, 2]
[4, 5]
[11, 2]
[11, 2]
[0, 2]
[4, 5]
[11, 2]
```

Comment: In your own words, what is the intended purpose of the `for i in newlist:` loop? In your own words, what is the intended purpose of the `newlist` variable? In your own words, what is the intended purpose of `return x` at the end? What do you expect to be returned, and why? Trace through your logic carefully.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the index and length of the 'True' elements.". `True` isn't a sequence, so it doesn't have a length. When you say that the answer should be `[[0,2],[4,5],[11,2]]`, what is the underlying reasoning?

Comment: The first number of the sublist is the index and the second number is the duration of the 'True' elements before the next number of the sequence (i.e. 3) is broken

Comment: So, the number of consecutive `True` elements starting at that point?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 2 print statements and that is why you are seeing it repeat.

Here, remove the return statement, because it is much better to print it -

```
for i in newlist:
        x = []
        x = [i[0],len(i)]
        print(x)
```

At the end, call the function

```
 find_episodes(data,2)
```

Comment: @ PCM my function still repeats itself with the amount of elements in the list. For instance, since there are 13 elements in the list, the output repeats itself 13 times

Comment: Well, look at the edit. Don't use for loops in this case and remove `[k]`

Answer (score 1):

You call your function `find_episodes` many times here :

```py
for k in range(len(data)):
    final = find_episodes(data[k],2)
```

Yet, your function actually does not depend on its arguments. Therefore, the exact same code will be executed `len(data)` times, thus the repeated output.

I believe you meant to execute `find_episodes` only once.

Finally, your `print(final)` is repetitive since the last `x` was already printed inside the function. That's why `[11, 2]` is printed twice every time.

Comment: Please look at the desired output. Do you think that result will come, if you call the function only once

Comment: I tested it and yes, calling the function only once gives exactly the desired output.

Comment: @PCM@vic.col961 ohh ok I understand now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What you say is right, but what happens is  if you `print(final)`, you get only one value, which is the last value that is in the for loop. So do not use return statement. Instead print the result

Comment: @PCM I agree that the return is useless but it is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: But even if this problem is solved, another problem will arise that only one value is printed.

Comment: @PCM Please try the code for yourself to verify what you're claiming. Here, simply removing the for loop and calling the function once prints **exactly** the desired output.